# ELKI: perform min-max normalization before running k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, normalization, data-mining, unsupervised-learning, elki

I am using one of the k-means implementations provided by ELKI in my Java project.

I would like to run a min-max normalization before actually running the k-means but I cannot understand what is the right way of doing it using the library API.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Set the filter parameter to include the min-max normalization filter?

Answer (score 0):

```
new InputStreamDatabaseConnection(is, filterlist, parser))
```

where `filterlist` is a `List<ObjectFilter>` and contains the `AttributeWiseMinMaxNormalization` filter *instance*. Or you use the Parameterization API, which handles default values and instantiation.

Comment: What if I need to use a `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection`? The constructor of that connection does not accept a list of filters.

Comment: Get the latest github version, which does have filters.